# How to add subscript and superscript text in kinetic text

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs, subscript, superscript

I am using kinetic.js to create a text object in a canvas.
  Now I need to create a text object with subscript and superscript 
e.g: H<sub>2</sub>O (here '2' will be subscript) and I am not able to create a kinetic text object with subscript.

Please help me if anyone knows a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**There's no native support for subscripts/superscripts in KineticJS Text objects.**

Option#1: Use a font that includes subscripted characters.

Option#2: Use a Kinetic Shape object.  The Shape object is used to create custom objects.  You can use regular html canvas fillText() calls inside your shape object's drawFunc function.  Here is a custom shape tutorial to get you started:  http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-shape-tutorial/

Comment: If i want to use Option#1 then will it be possible to create a single text object with different font size.. I mean to say for H2O 'H' and 'O' will be in normal font size and '2' will be subscripted font in a single text object.

Comment: Yes--if you mean the 2 will be subscripted, check out this reference for info about arial font's extended codes for subscripting numbers:  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/arial_unicode_ms/blockview.htm?block=superscripts_and_subscripts